# Implicit method to solve a system of ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I'm looking for the vector valued solution $y(t)=(y_1(t),\ldots,y_n(t))$ of a linear system of ODEs in the form of

$$y'(t)=f(t,y(t)),\ \ \ \mathrm{where}\ f(t,y)=M\cdot y+g(t)$$

The matrix $M \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and the continuous, vector valued function $g$ are given.

Furthermore we have an initial value, given as a vector:

$$y(0)=y_0, \ \ \ y_0 \in \mathbb R^n$$

**Method:**

One way to approximate the solution at $t=h$ numerically, is to choose an (appropriate) matrix $A=(a_{ij}) \in \mathbb R^{s \times s}$, a parameter vector $c=(c_i) \in \mathbb R^s$ $(0 \leq c_i \leq 1)$ and a vector $b=(b_i) \in \mathbb R^s$. And write down the following system of $s \cdot n$ equations and $s \cdot n$ unknowns:

\begin{align}\tag{1} &y_1=y_0+h(a_{11}f(c_1h,y_1)+\ldots +a_{1s}f(c_sh,y_s))\\&\vdots\\&y_s=y_0+h(a_{s1}f(c_1h,y_1)+\ldots +a_{ss}f(c_sh,y_s))\end{align}

where $y_i=(y_{i,1},\ldots,y_{i,n}) \in \mathbb R^n, i=1,\ldots,s$ have to be determined. After this system is solved, an approximation of the solution $y(t)$ at $t=h$ is given by

$$\tag{2}y_0+h(b_1f(c_1h,y_1)+\ldots+b_sf(c_sh,y_s)$$

> How can I show that the system of equations (1) has an unique solution for sufficiently small stepsize $h$?
>
> Furthermore, does this method have a specific name? I'm also looking for a matlab code, that solves (1) and evaluates (2)

I don't understand your definition of $F$. Don't we have $Y=Y_0+hAF(T,Y)$ with $F(T,Y)$ defined as
$F(T,Y):=\begin{pmatrix}f(c_1h,y_1) & \dots & f(c_1h,y_1)\\ \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\ f(c_sh,y_s) & \dots & f(c_sh,y_s) \end{pmatrix}$.

Furthermore, why is $Y=Y_0+hAF(T,Y)$ a fixed-point equation? What exactly does fixed point equation mean? In Banachs theorem we have $x_{n+1}=\phi(x_n)$.

Do we need $h$ small enough such that $hL\max_{i}\sum_j|a_{ij}|<1$? (So that we have a contracting map)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General argument based on the implicit function theorem

The implicit system that you have to solve is
$$
y_i=y_0+h\bigl(a_{i1}f(t_1,y-1)+...+a_{is}f(t_s,y_s)\bigr).\tag{1a}
$$
This can be written as one big system 
$$Y=Y_0+h(A\otimes I)F(T,Y),\tag{1b}$$ 
where
$$
Y=\pmatrix{y_1\\\vdots\\y_s}, ~~Y_0=\pmatrix{y_0\\\vdots\\y_0}, ~~ F(T,Y)=\pmatrix{f(t_1,y_1)\\\vdots\\f(t_s,y_s)}
$$
and the tensor product is the Kronecker product. For $h=0$ this has the obvious and unique solution $Y=Y_0$. The composite map $F$ is as smooth as the given function $f$, and $Y\mapsto Y-h(A\otimes I)F(T,Y)$ has an invertible Jacobian at $Y=Y_0$ for sufficiently small $h$. The existence and uniqueness of the solution of equation (1) in dependence of $h$ in some small interval around $0$ can now be asserted via the implicit function theorem.

### Direct solution in the linear case

If $f(t,y)=My+g(t)$ as per question, then the implicit system is in fact linear and can be solved as an $ns\times ns$ system,
$$
Y=Y_0+h(A\otimes I)[(I\otimes M)Y+G(T)]
\\\implies\\
Y=[I-h(A\otimes M)]^{-1}[Y_0+h(A\otimes I)G(T)]
$$
where $G(T)$ is again the vertically stacked collection of vectors $(g(t_1),...,g(t_s))$.

As no further numerical method is involved, the only restriction on $h$ is that $h^{-1}$ should not be an eigenvalue of $(A\otimes M)$. This is satisfied if $h\|A\|\,\|M\|<1$.

### Using the Banach fixed-point theorem directly for the non-linear case

One can make this a bit more quantitative using the Banach fixed-point theorem for the fixed-point map $$P(Y)=Y_0+h(A\otimes I)F(T,Y).$$ Using a suitable composite norm on $Y$, for instance $\|Y\|=\max_{k=1,..,s}\|y_k\|$, one finds that $P$ has a Lipschitz constant $$L(P)=h\|A\|\,L(f)$$ on some ball $\|Y-Y_0\|\le R$ where $R$ is such that $f$ has Lipschitz constant $L(f)$ on $\|y-y_0\|\le R$. Choosing $h$ small enough, one can achieve $L(P)\le\frac12$.

Then with 
$$\|P(Y)-Y_0\|\le \|P(Y_0)-Y_0\|+\|P(Y)-P(Y_0)\|\le h\|A\|\|F(T,Y_0)\|+L(P)\|Y-Y_0\|$$ 
one needs to ensure that also the first term is smaller than $R/2$ to have $\|Y-Y_0\|\le R\implies \|P(Y)-Y_0\|\le R$ so that all conditions of the fixed-point theorem are satisfied.

### Some classes of implicit methods

Examples that you might want to explore are the Gauß methods and the SDIRK methods. The Gauß methods, based on Gauß integration, have the highest order for the number of stages. The SDIRK methods (Singly Diagonally Implicit Runge-Kutta) have a lower triangular matrix $(a_{ij})$ with the same entry on the diagonal. This has the advantage that the implicit system can be solved stage-by-stage, and in each stage a simplified Newton method can be employed that has the same matrix.

Butcher tableaus for some lower order examples can be found in [these slides of Butcher's](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/IRK.pdf).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the implicit function theorem? I think the author forgot to write down the assumption that f is lipschitz continuous. Could we use banach's fixed-point theorem to show that it is uniquely solvable? (assuming f is lipschitz continuous)

Comment: Note that to get the full advantages of an order $p$ method you need that $f$ is $p$ times continuously differentiable, so that locally Lipschitz is already implied.

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly do we use Banach here? We need a complete metric space and a contracting mapping. What are those in our case?

Comment: Your space is a ball around $Y_0$, your map is given by the fixed-point equation, it is contracting if $h$ is small enough, using the Lipschitz constant and a suitable norm of $(|a_{ij}|)$ you can also quantify the allowed size of $h$.

Comment: I added some questions above

Comment: Yes to the inequality. You also need that the "Euler step" from $Y_0$ to $P(Y_0)$ is small enough so that is is well inside the set where the Lipschitz constant of $f$ is valid. If it is globally valid, then there is no restriction from this and only $h\|A\|L<1$ is to be satisfied.

Comment: Why do we need the Kronecker product? Isn't the system simply $Y=Y_0+hAF(T,Y)$? In case you mean the 1x1 Identity matrix it doesn't do anything, so I was wondering. (If you mean a different dimension than 1x1, I don't see why it is correct)

Comment: Yes, the ODE system might actually be a system, that is, the $y$ might be vectors and $f$ might be vector valued. Then you have to somehow formalize the vector combinations in the stages.

Comment: What do you mean? I would just write $Y=Y_0+hAF(T,Y)$ instead of $Y=Y_0+h(A\otimes I)F(T,Y),\tag{1b}$ and don't change anything else.

And when determining $L(P)$, why do we not care about the summand $Y_0$?

Comment: $A$ is an $s\times s$ matrix. $F$ contains $s$ instances of values of $f$, so has dimension $ns$. Do you see the need to fill up the dimensions? // Constants do not contribute to Lipschitz constants, as that deals with differences where constant terms cancel.

Comment: Yes I see. So is the kronecker product a correct way to eliminate this dimensions-problem the way you implemented it in your answer? (Where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix)

Comment: Yes, that's why I used it.

Comment: one last question. For the contraction, don't we have to show that $\|P(Y)-P(Y_0)\|\leq k\|Y-Y_0\|$ for some $0\leq k <1$? Why do we show $\|Y-Y_0\|\le R\implies \|P(Y)-Y_0\|\le R$ instead?

Comment: You need some set $M$ so that $P$ maps it into itself. One typical example is some ball around $Y_0$, $M=B_R(Y_0)$. You can not take the full space if the Lipschitz constant is only locally valid.

Comment: I added a screenshot above. How can I use the data to show that the order of the gauss method I used is $p=4$? On wikipedia it says $\tau \leq \mathcal O(h^{p+1})$, where $\tau$ is the local truncation error so I need to show that $\tau \leq \mathcal O(h^{5})$ but how can I do this?

Comment: An order 4 method only has useful step sizes down to $Lh\sim\sqrt[5]\mu$ where $\mu=10^{-16}$ is the machine constant, in typical test examples that gives $h=0.001$ as the smallest useful step size. // You should print the last column in scientific notation. You could add a column where you divide the error by $h^5$. If the method order is 4, this should give an almost constant factor for about $h=0.001$ to $h=0.05$.

Comment: You should also add hints on how to reconstruct your table, it is usually not very helpful to just have raw numbers without context.